# Recursively get values from a record

Tags: clojure

I have the following code:

```
(defrecord Stoptest [&args])
(def test (Stoptest. [:c101 :main-office :a1]))

; gets the values out 
(doseq [arg (:&args test)] (print arg))
```

Is there a way in which I can recur around args and put the values into a lazy sequence?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're asking? As the question is written, I'm finding it difficult to discern what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to get the values :c101 :main-office and put them into a sequence. At the minute all I've managed to do with them is print them out. Is there a way in which i can get each value and assign it to a variable to be used elsewhere?

Comment: no idea what your plan was with `&args` but as it stands you probably want `(:&args test)`

Comment: @CS456 In that case, wouldn't `(seq (:&args test))` and `(let [{[a b c] :&args} test] ,,,)` work, respectively?